# node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build error install with npm on OSX

Tags: sqlite, npm, ghost-blog, node-gyp

Running on OSX, node version 0.12.0, running

```
npm install --production
```

for Ghost trying to install sqlite3 v. 3.0.4 I get the following error:

```
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead. gyp: /Users/USER/.node/common.gypi not found (cwd:
/Users/USER/Documents/personal_website/ghost/node_modules/sqlite3) while reading includes of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp gyp 
ERR! configure error  gyp 
ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1 gyp 
ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:343:16) gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17) gyp ERR! stack     at
Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1067:12) gyp     

ERR! System Darwin 14.1.0 gyp ERR! command "node"
"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--name=sqlite3" "--configuration=Release" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--version=3.0.4" "--major=3" "--patch=4" "--runtime=node" "--node_abi=node-v14" "--platform=darwin" "--target_platform=darwin" "--arch=x64" "--target_arch=x64" "--module_main=./lib/sqlite3" "--host=https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/" "--module_path=/Users/USER/Documents/personal_website/ghost/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v14-darwin-x64" "--module=/Users/USER/Documents/personal_website/ghost/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v14-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node" "--remote_path=./sqlite3/v3.0.4/" "--package_name=node-v14-darwin-x64.tar.gz" "--staged_tarball=build/stage/sqlite3/v3.0.4/node-v14-darwin-x64.tar.gz" "--hosted_path=https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.0.4/" "--hosted_tarball=https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.0.4/node-v14-darwin-x64.tar.gz" "--nodedir=/Users/USER/.node" gyp 
ERR! cwd /Users/USER/Documents/personal_website/ghost/node_modules/sqlite3 gyp 

ERR! node -v v0.12.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2 gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! Darwin 14.1.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--production"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! sqlite3@3.0.4 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@3.0.4 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the sqlite3 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sqlite3
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I do have /usr/local/share/npm/bin in my PATH.

Comment: did you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

When trying to install ghost I also get this error.  It looks like something is wrong with node-sqlite3, as I've seen other people posting about this error.  Once node-sqlite3 is fixed there may be more issues though:

Ghost doesn't currently support node 0.12.x yet.  From the README.md:

> Ghost requires Node v0.10.x

There is more info at https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/4240

I'll probably just end up installing an older version of node until ghost has a new release.

Answer (score 1):

`npm i sqlite3 --build-from-source` may work

Answer (score 0):

I got that error too. After downgrade nodejs to 0.10.9 with npm version 2.5.1 I can do `npm install --production` without error

Answer (score 0):

If you download Ghost directly from the github repo a lot of these issues that arise due to the `package.json` file are already resolved.

For instance, you have these notable changes that solve some install issues:

`"engines": {
        "node": "~0.10.0 || ~0.12.0",
        "iojs": "~1.2.0"
    },`

And also in *dependencies*:

`"html-to-text": "1.2.0",
        "sqlite3": "3.0.5",`

Answer (score 0):

Console appeared like this:

> node pre gyp install --fallback-to-build

This is installed into a 32 bit version.
Waiting for a while, it automatically becomes 64 bit.
And just fine.